# How can I control React Leaflet height and width?

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm trying to display position on map using basic React Leaflet.
But I face an issue on container height and width.

I apply CSS rule on .leaflet-container class and also tried tailwind CSS  for resizing the container.But nothing is working.

React Leaflet v4.0